# Adding tools to list view Window forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Was wondering can we create a DateTimePicker and put it into list view. I have a list view with 2 columnheader (Item,Due Date). In the Due Date column, users are allowed to key in the due date with the help of DateTimePicker.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 DateTimePicker dtp = new DateTimePicker();
 ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] { item, dtp });
```

If I create the dtp and use the lvItem.SubItem.Items.Add method will it works?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a custom control as needed, here you can get quite creative in terms of the things you can achieve, although what you are attempting is complex... See this link on basic approach [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx)

or another link for C#

[Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235628(v=vs.80).aspx)